# Sphinx footnotes across pages or equivalent

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a document with some footnotes:

**doc.rst**

```
This sentence needs clarification\ [#fn1]_.
```

If I place the footnote in the same file, it works fine. However, I'd like to have a separate file with footnotes from a couple of different documents:

**supplement.rst**

```
[#fn1] A word of explanation.
```

This gives me two sets of warnings. First a warning in `supplement.rst`:

```
...supplement.rst:1: WARNING: Footnote [#] is not referenced.
```

Then a pair of warnings in `doc.rst`:

```
...doc.rst:1: WARNING: Too many autonumbered footnote references: only 0 corresponding footnotes available.
...doc.rst:1: WARNING: Unknown target name "fn1".
```

The reference in `doc.html` is rendered as a link with text `[#fn1]_` which goes nowhere, and the number to the left of the note in `supplement.html` is greyed out.

How do I implement cross-document footnotes in sphinx?

Comment: The scope of footnotes is limited to the document only, not the entire document set. You could implement [citations](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#citations) or a [glossary](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#glossary).

Comment: @Steve. Cousins are exactly what I'm looking for. If you draft an answer, if be happy to accept it.

Comment: "Cousins"? LOL, I think that's illegal in most states in the US. I love autocorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scope of footnotes is limited to the document only, and is not global for the entire document set. You could implement [citations](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#citations) or a [glossary](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#glossary).